# Put cart totals below the cart products in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the **cart page**, the cart *totals* are the above the cart products:

[image]

I want the "totals" to go below the products table, inside the cart form:

[image]

Question:

1. Would doing this affect the checkout process?
2. Can I achieve this by copying the contents of `totals.html` inside `form.phtml`? The path:

   > app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

The `checkout_cart_index.xml` in the theme is:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

The full code of `checkout_cart_index.xml` is in **[this Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vWiLT9TP)**.

Comment: It will not affect the checkout process, & there is no need to do copy the code from **`totals.html`** to **`form.phtml`**.
Can you put the code of `checkout_index.index.xml`

Comment: Is it not `checkout_cart_index.xml`?

Comment: Yes for cart it is `checkout_cart_index.xml`

Comment: I think it is not that `xml` file please put the `xml` file which is present in your `theme/Magento_Checkout`

Comment: That _is_ the XML file in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

I copied `checkout_cart_index.xml`to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

In this file I added:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.items" after="checkout.cart.form"/>
```

The totals went under the products.